# Reduce Multiple Calls To Database

Tags: c#, database, vb.net

I have a code a base that iterates through a list of records and does the follwing

```
'select * from Table to see if fields exist

then later in the interation
'select * from Table to retreive some data

then farther down in the interation
select field1, field2 from Table to get certain pieces of information
```

I need to do all of these functions for each record. Would the process speed up if I called the query once for each record and hold the data in a datatable and retreive what I need from there? Or is there another more efficient way to not have to make 3 db calls to the same table which will speed up the process?

Comment: Why don't you just `SELECT` all the fields you're going to need through the entire iteration at the start and then handle the case if they don't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache query data to [`System.Data.DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.11).aspx). To simplify things I has written CMyDynaset class, which populates DataTable with data from DB. Here how to use it for example with MySQL:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namesapce MyProg
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string strMyConnection = "Host=localhost;Database=mydb;User Id=myuser;Password=mypsw";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(strMyConnection))
            {
                using (MyDb.CMyDynaset dyn = new MyDb.CMyDynaset(myConnection, MySqlClientFactory.Instance))
                {
                    // populate dyn.Table (System.Data.DataTable)
                    dyn.Init("select * from Table");
                    dyn.Load();

                    // access fields
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dyn.Table.Columns)
                    {
                        // ...
                    }

                    // get data
                    long nCountAll = dyn.Table.Rows.Count; // rows count
                    foreach (DataRow row in dyn.Table.Rows)
                    {
                        Object val1 = row[1]; // acess by index
                        Object val2 = row["id"]; // acess by name

                        // ...
                    }

                    // update data
                    dyn.Table.Rows[0]["name"] = "ABC";
                    dyn.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CMyDynaset class (*CMyDynaset.cs*):

```
// CMyDynaset.cs
using System;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace MyDb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CMyDynaset.
    /// </summary>
    public class CMyDynaset : IDisposable
    {
        public System.Data.DataTable Table = null;
        // private
        private DbConnection myConnection = null;
        private DbProviderFactory myFactory = null;
        private DbDataAdapter dataAdap = null;
        private DbCommandBuilder cmdBld = null;
        private bool bIsSchema = false;

        public CMyDynaset(DbConnection conn, DbProviderFactory factory)
        {
            this.myConnection = conn;
            this.myFactory = factory;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this.Table != null)
            {
                this.Table.Dispose();
                this.Table = null;
            }
            if (this.cmdBld != null)
            {
                this.cmdBld.Dispose();
                this.cmdBld = null;
            }
            if (this.dataAdap != null)
            {
                this.dataAdap.Dispose();
                this.dataAdap = null;
            }
            // This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
            // Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
            // take this object off the finalization queue
            // and prevent finalization code for this object
            // from executing a second time.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        #endregion

        // Init
        public void Init(string strSelect)
        {
            DbCommand cmdSel = this.myConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmdSel.CommandText = strSelect;

            this.dataAdap = this.myFactory.CreateDataAdapter();
            this.dataAdap.SelectCommand = cmdSel;
            this.cmdBld = this.myFactory.CreateCommandBuilder();
            this.cmdBld.DataAdapter = this.dataAdap;

            this.Table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            // schema
            this.bIsSchema = false;
        }

        public void AddParameter(string name, object value)
        {
            DbParameter param = this.dataAdap.SelectCommand.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = name;
            param.Value = value;
            this.dataAdap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        public void AddParameter(DbParameter param)
        {
            this.dataAdap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        // Open, Close
        private void Open(ref bool bClose)
        {
            if (this.myConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                this.myConnection.Open();
                bClose = true;
            }
            if (!this.bIsSchema)
            {   // schema
                this.dataAdap.FillSchema(this.Table, System.Data.SchemaType.Mapped);
                this.bIsSchema = true;
            }
        }

        private void Close(bool bClose)
        {
            if (bClose)
                this.myConnection.Close();
        }

        // Load, Update
        public void Load()
        {
            bool bClose = false;
            try
            {
                this.Table.Clear();
                this.Open(ref bClose);
                this.dataAdap.Fill(this.Table);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Close(bClose);
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            bool bClose = false;
            try
            {
                this.Open(ref bClose);
                this.dataAdap.Update(this.Table);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) 
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Close(bClose);
            }
        }
    }
}
```